# Selecting only 1 checkbox (Don't think I can use radio buttons)

Tags: php

I have a bit of an issue I need help with.

I have a whole heap of images that need to be either "accepted" or "rejected"
So basically the page will have a heap of images with an accept and reject checkbox and then a save button at the bottom of the page. These images are actually GD generated images from a string pulled from a MySQL database. These images are generated and displayed using a while loop in PHP.

My issue is at the moment the checkboxes can both be selected at the same time and it doesnt make sense to be able to accept and reject at the same time. I understand radio buttons are for this however it isn't possible for me to have a form for every image and I have to be able to distinguish which accept/rejection was for each image in the next action page.

This is basically what I have but I can't be making a form over and over while im looping.

```
echo "<form name=\"selections\" action=\"processselections.php\" method=\"post\">";
echo "<div>";
echo "Accept: <input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"accept\" value=\"accept" . $row[0] . " class=\"checkbox\"\">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Reject: <input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"reject\" value=\"reject" . $row[0] . "\">";
echo "</div>";
echo "</form>";
```

Comment: Radio buttons are checkboxes that allow only one to be on at a time. What else COULD you use? Any other kind of solution you came up with would be re-inventing radio buttons.

Comment: But im going to have a lot of Accept/Reject button groups. How do I split up the radio button groups without a whole heap of forms.

Comment: @KriiV: Can you like link to a semi-working example of what you have? I'm not following you.

Comment: radio button behavior is limited to buttons that have the same name... differ the names and you can make all the radio groups you want

Comment: No, it would not, just give them different names: `<input type="radio" name="imageID.." id="imageID.." value="accept" /><label for="imageID..">accept</label>`

Comment: You don't need a whole new form for each radio button group. As long as each group is named differently (or if you have the values submit to an array) then a single form is all you need.

Comment: @Phillip Unfortunately it would really hard for me to do that :(  Okay Recode and winterblood that seems alright, im going to have to think about how its going to work.

Comment: I think you'll find that a loop to create your table (and selectors) is what you're gonna need to work with large amounts of data.  Not sure exactly what that would look like yet because your question is too vague.

Comment: try `echo "Accept: <input type=\"radio\" name=\"img" . $row[0] . "\" value=\"accept\"> Reject: <input type=\"radio\" name=\"img" . $row[0] . "\" value=\"reject\">";` The name is the same for both accept/reject, and you get the value of the selected.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `radio button` for this, also add `name` for radio grouping use `your image id`

```
echo "<form name='selections' action='processselections.php' method='post'>";
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo "<div>";
    echo "Accept: 
     <input type='radio' name='accept_reject_".$row[0]."' value='accept".$row[0]."'/>
     &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Reject: 
     <input type='radio' name='accept_reject_".$row[0]."' value='reject".$row[0]."'/>";
    echo "</div>";
}
echo "</form>";
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use only one checkbox by a pic:

- if checkbox is selected, the user accepts
- if checkbox is NOT selected, the user reject

It's simply well designed to have only one checkbox.

Hope that's help you.
Regards

Comment: Could work but the OPs question is still too vague for me to feel confident in the answer.

Comment: @user1587368: This works only if the state 'has not made a decision' doesn't need to be represented. (Gray half-ticked state?)

Comment: I think this would work. In my case it would be best to have the checkbox for Accept already ticked and that is easy to do. This is a really simple solution, thank you!